# How to make a list comprehension iterate a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, iteration

We want a list comprehension to iterate a function, for example this is what we want:

```
list1 = [3, 1, 2]
list2 = [f(f(f())), f(), f(f())]
```

How would this be possible?

Comment: It sounds like you would be happier with `functools.reduce()`, but it's hard to tell exactly what you are trying to do. A small concrete example with actual data and expected result would help.

Comment: The question is: why do you want to do this as a list comprehension and not a regular loop?

Comment: im lazy and desperate to do list comprehension

Comment: Do you want to do something different than `list2 = [f(n) for n in list1]`? If so, can you show the code that does this without a list comprehension?

Comment: What should be the function argument in the innermost call?

Comment: How would the elements (as opposed to the size) of `list1` be used at all?

Comment: @DavisHerring It looks like each value in `list1` specifies the nesting depth of the function calls for that position in the result list.

Comment: @TomKarzes: That seems plausible, but then the list comprehension is irrelevant: it can just be `y=f(f(…)) # n times` (with the same mysterious innermost argument).

Comment: @DavisHerring Consider `list1 = [3, 1, 2]`. OP wants (or appears to want) `list2 = [f(f(f())), f(), f(f())]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write a function that calls a function `n` times. Then call that in the list comprehension.

```
def call_n(func, n, arg):
    res = arg
    for _ in range(n):
        res = func(res)
    return res

list2 = [call_n(f, i, initial_value) for i in list1]
```

Comment: You're right. I'm still not immune to fencepost errors.

Comment: Note that this performs a quadratic number of function calls for an input like `range(n)`.  That might be required semantically, but if the use case really is various numbers of nestings of the same function, it might be worth caching.

Comment: @DavisHerring Good point, assuming the function is idempotent. In a list comprehension that could probably be done using the walrus operator.